# MySQL Load XML Error - Many child elements with different attributes?

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm trying to load an XML file into a MySQL table using LOAD XML, and I'm continually getting a MySQL error `1263: Column set to default value; NULL supplied to NOT NULL column 'kickoffs' at row 1.`

Here is a snippet of my XML file:

```
# Many <Player> elements, each with about 70 <PlyrData> grandchildren elements

<Match id="2345" timestamp="20130124T162429" stadium_id="65">
    <TmInfo>
        <Team team_id="234" team_name="Aces">
            <Player id="45645" player_name="Elmer Fudd" pos_id="15">
                <PlyrDatas>
                  <PlyrData player_id="45645" />
                  <PlyrData team_id="234" />
                  <PlyrData kickoffs="0" />
                  <PlyrData kick_rec="0" />
                  <PlyrData kicks="8" />
                  <PlyrData penalties="0" />
                  <PlyrData errors="0" />
                  <PlyrData penalty_success="0" />
                  <PlyrData turnovers="0" />
                  ....
                </PlyrDatas>
            </Player>
        </Team>
    </TmInfo>
</Match>
```

And here is the SQL for the table it should go into.

```
USE matchdata;      

CREATE TABLE plyr_match_data (
    player_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    team_id TINYINT NOT NULL,
    game_id INT NOT NULL,
    kickoffs  TINYINT NOT NULL,
    kicks  TINYINT NOT NULL,
    penalties  TINYINT NOT NULL,
    errors  TINYINT NOT NULL,
    penalty_success  TINYINT NOT NULL,
    turnovers  TINYINT NOT NULL
    );
```

And here is the LOAD XML code. My hunch is that the issue lies in the `<PlyrDatas>` element having many `<PlyrData>` elements, each with a different attribute.  Doing [a little research](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2010/09/26/load-xml-local-infile/) I thought I had found that I could identify the `<PlyrDatas>` tag as the row, and it would grab all of the child element attributes as the columns.

Looking at the LOAD XML man page at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html, I haven't found anything that indicates that this method works.

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Rob\\Documents\\data_analysis\\match_data\\Aces_v_Kings.xml'
    INTO TABLE plyr_match_data
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<PlyrDatas>';
```

Is there a way to import this XML file using LOAD XML so the multiple `<PlyrData>` element attributes are imported into columns?  Is there a different way to do this?

I've read through many of the related posts and haven't found anything that I think pertains directly to this specific issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The manual describes 3 different XML formats that are supported. Your file doesn't match any of them.

Comment: Have you thought about putting all attributes in the same node <PlyrData>?

Comment: wchiquito, I'm provided the XML file "as is". Any suggestions for modifying it programmatically?  I suspect that it would need to be done using XSLT, which I'm not really familiar with.

Comment: I did put all the attributes in the same node to test the fix, and it does work. But I'll need to find a way to transform the XML, as there are many, many <PlyrData> elements over many, many XML files.